# Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 3

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm using the MySQL module for NodeJS, however I keep getting the following error after approximately 10 requests to the database. I'm using the following code to connect to the DB:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "10.37.100.15",
    user: process.env.MYSQLUSR,
    password: process.env.MYSQLPASSWD,
    database: process.env.MYSQLDB
});
```

Then I use `con.query(sqlStatement, function (err, result, fields) {<function>})`. I already tried changing the `max_allowed_packet` to 500M on the server but this didn't fix the issue. This is the full error:

```
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 3
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.handleParserError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:380:10)
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:478:10)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: This is looking like a server error (though there is chance its still in the mysql-nodejs connector). Which MySQL version? Which mysql-nodejs version? What are the 10 queries? If you repeat the queries in connector or a client program is the same error generated?

Comment: @danblack
MySQL version: `mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`
mysql-nodejs version: 2.18.1
There was actually only 1 query this time it was: 
`SELECT privateKey FROM keyPairs WHERE publicKey='website';`, I dont get any errors when executing this query in mysql workbench. One other thing to note is that all queries are done over a single connection that is opened as soon as the code starts running, I then get his error after arround 10 hours.

Comment: My guess is that OP used 1 connection to run multiple queries in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) is 8 hrs.

I'd suspect the mysql-nodejs version isn't resetting the expected packet count on re-connection.

In a test environment you can reduce the `wait_timeout`.

It quite possibly is:

- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2534
- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2451

Last comment on #2534 is "I change my connection from mysql.createConnection to mysql.createPool, the error never happen again"

Comment: I'm having the exact issue when using createPool.

Comment: I suspect in hindsight that @Evert was correct in the comment, You're using the same connection in multiple threads. As the connection has state, the query needs to be complete before another query is pushed through the same connection.

Comment: Although I'm sure, to do the queries one by one using the inner callbacks, I'll check if I did this anywhere.

Comment: Do multiple application threads use the same connection object at the same time?

Comment: I'm working without the cluster configuration of node for now, so basically no possible other threads that can use the connection in between.

Comment: @SercanSametSavran I recommend a new question or bug report containing the mysqljs version, the server version, and a minimal sample code.