# Error connecting to MySQL database: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0

Tags: mysql, database, next.js

I am working on a Next.js project that uses MySQL as the database. When I run the application, I encounter the following error after a few runs: "Error connecting to database: Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0". However, after building the application, the error does not occur, and it only happens in the local development environment.

Here is the complete error stack trace:

```
Error connecting to database: Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (Pool.js:48:16)
    at eval (db.js:20:12)
    at Object.(api)/./src/utils/db.js (getAllMonthlySession.js:42:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (getAllMonthlySession.js:5:67)
    at Object.(api)/./src/pages/api/customer_panel/appointment/getAllMonthlySession.js (getAllMonthlySession.js:32:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (getAllMonthlySession.js:52:39)
    at getAllMonthlySession.js:53:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (getAllMonthlySession.js:56:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at async DevServer.runImpl (base-server.js:432:29)
    at async DevServer.run (next-dev-server.js:814:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (base-server.js:375:20)
    at async base-server.js:157:99 {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
}
```

I would appreciate any insights into why this error is occurring and how I can fix it. Thank you!

And here is my db.js

```
import mysql from 'mysql';

// Keeping the variable name connection instead of pool :') NVM, The deadline is tight

//Updating DB Connection:
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  multipleStatements: true,
  connectTimeout: 60000,
});

connection.getConnection((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to database');
  }
});

export default connection;
```

I have tried adjusting the connectionLimit and other configurations, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70917809/error-in-sql-to-node-js-error-packets-out-of-order-got-45-expected-0

Comment: @M.Ryan I have checked the link, I didn't use any port or end() connections. I have updated the question with my db.js code. Please give it a check. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645884/error-packets-out-of-order-got-0-expected-3)

Comment: @FabioNettis I'm already using createPool and i don't think wait_time is the issue here. Cuz From the same server other projects are running fine with that configuration.